# "Failed to instantiate component or class" when calling Craft module

Tags: craft3, modules

I created a module with the pluginfactory generator. The module is used for generating a zip file with all the files belonging to a project.

In the `composer.json` file, I added the following:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "zipassetscraft3module\\": "modules/zipassetscraft3module"
    }
  },
```

in the `config/app.php` I added:

```
'modules' => [
      'zip-assets-craft-3-module' => \modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module::class,
    ],
```

In the file `controllers/DefaultController.php` I added a function called `actionDownload()` as well as a `download()` function in the file `services/ZipAssetsCraft3ModuleService.php`

On the website I have a form with the following url as action: `https://default.com/actions/zip-assets-craft-3-module/default/download`

When I submit the form, I get an error:

> Invalid Configuration – yii\base\InvalidConfigException Failed to
>   instantiate component or class
>   "modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module".
>
> Caused by: ReflectionException Class
>   modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module does not exist

I have dumped the composer autoload, but I don't know why it's not working. Any ideas what I need to change to get this working?

This is the file structure of the module: 
[image]

So the error message says, there is a class missing, in which file is this class looked for?

Comment: Try to remove `\modules` from `\modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module::class` in your `config/app.php`

Comment: You don't mention bootstrapping your module; that might be what you're missing. You should have a bootstrap array in `config/app.php`, add the module "key" you created above to the bootstrap array: `'bootstrap' => ['zip-assets-craft-3-module'],`...

Comment: @Oli that doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: @JalenDavenport when I do this, the error message appears immediately and not only when I call the action. I updated my question and added a screenshot with the file structure

Comment: @obs ah so you're referencing a Class by the name of `ReflectionException` in your `ZipAssetsCraft3Module.php` file that PHP can't find. Any chance you could post the contents of that file or at least the snippet that contains `ReflectionException`?

Comment: @JalenDavenport the error message says "Class modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module does not exist
in /www/[...]/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/di/Container.php at line 431". I'm afraid this doesn't help much. In the docs, there is a section about the "Module class": https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/extend/module-guide.html#the-module-class. I don't have a file Module.php in my module, do I need one?

Comment: @obs if you're getting a different error it would be helpful to explain where you're seeing it and what you changed since the original post. Maybe if you could share your whole codebase in a GitHub repo (or something like that) I could take a quick look... Alternatively, you could post something over in the Craft Discord group, as this isn't a question one can easily answer without a lot more info.

Comment: @JalenDavenport the codebase of the module is from https://pluginfactory.io/. I then call this action via a form submit: `https://[domain]/actions/zip-assets-craft-3-module/default/download`
For this I have the function `download()` in `services/ZipAssetsCraft3ModuleService.php`

Comment: I found the right paths in the readme.md file.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. So how i solved it is to modify the modules array like this and now the module is loading:

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        'zip-assets-craft-3-module' => [
            'class' => \modules\zipassetscraft3module\ZipAssetsCraft3Module::class,
        ],
    ],
    'bootstrap' => ['zip-assets-craft-3-module'],
];
```